# HTMl 5 Canvas Koch Fractcal

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

What I'm asking today is to help with a Koch algorithm, to keep increasing the iterations on a line, without having to manually re-doing the process again and again. This is what I've got so far.

```
KochStar.prototype.draw = function (context) {

    var StartPoint = new Vector(this.getStart().getX(), this.getStart().getY());
    var MiddlePoint = new Vector(this.getMiddle().getX(), this.getMiddle().getY());
    var EndPoint = new Vector(this.getEnd().getX(), this.getEnd().getY());


    //iteration 1, left side
    var v1 = MiddlePoint.copy();
    v1.subtract(StartPoint);
    v1.divide(3);
    var P1 = StartPoint.copy();
    P1.add(v1);


    var v1R = v1.copy();
    v1R.rotate(-Math.PI/3);
    var P2 = P1.copy();
    P2.add(v1R);

    var v1R2 = v1.copy();
    v1R2.rotate(Math.PI/3);
    var P3 = P2.copy();
    P3.add(v1R2);
```

And what this is currently doing is taking a vector dividing it into three segments and rotating 2 of them by 60 Degrees to create the a triangle 'bump' on a simple straight line.

For what I'm asking is that for every time a start and an end point is called apply the math from earlier to automatically create the curve, and keep doing this for 'x' amount of iterations.

**--------------UPDATE----------------**

Okay so far what i've done is, which is going through the Arrays and doing each point. However What i really need it for an iteration part for example.  Start at A Go to B between A and B Do this: A[C-D-E]B like so.

What i need next is for something to take C-D from that Array and make those two points my Start and End and in between do the Math from earlier.

```
    KochStar.prototype.draw = function (context) {
        var pArrayX = new Array(P1.getX(), P2.getX(), P3.getX());
        var pArrayY = new Array(P1.getY(), P2.getY(), P3.getY());

        var p1ArrayX = new Array(P1a.getX(), P2a.getX(), P3a.getX());
        var p1ArrayY = new Array(P1a.getY(), P2a.getX(), P3a.getY());

        var p2ArrayX = new Array(P1b.getX(), P2b.getX(), P3b.getX());
        var p2ArrayY = new Array(P1b.getY(), P2b.getX(), P3b.getY());

        var iterat;

        context.save()
        context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth = "5";
        context.strokeStyle = "red";
        context.fillStyle = "Yellow";


    context.lineTo(StartPoint.getX(),StartPoint.getY());
              for (var i = 0; i < pArrayX.length; i++) {
                 var x = pArrayX[i];
                 var y = pArrayY[i];
                 context.lineTo(x, y); 
             }  

        context.lineTo(MiddlePoint.getX(),MiddlePoint.getY()); 
             for (var p = 0; p < p1ArrayX.length; p++) {
                var x1 = p1ArrayX[p];
                var y1 = p1ArrayY[p];
                context.lineTo(x1, y1); 
            }     

        context.lineTo(EndPoint.getX(),EndPoint.getY())
            for (var z = 0; z < p2ArrayX.length; z++) {
                var x2 = p2ArrayX[z];
                var y2 = p2ArrayY[z];
                context.lineTo(x2, y2); 
            } 
    context.lineTo(StartPoint.getX(),StartPoint.getY())
```

this was mentioned earlier and this is what i'm trying to achive!
Any help would be fantastic!

> Is there a reason you need the points, other than drawing them? You can get the canvas context to do all the math for you in transformations, if all you need is to draw it. If you need the points, have the KochStar constructor do all the math with a function that recursively "Koch-ifies" each successive pair of points in an array into an array of 4 points and concatenates them. Keep the resulting array, iterate over it in draw with a call to lineTo. – sqykly

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion on one approach:

- Keep each line in the koch fractal as single objects.
- Keep a center point of the fractal  so you will know what direction the new lines will point at (the middle split)
- Iterate over the first three lines and divide them into three parts (so you have the points), insert the new point in the middle.
- Use the new points to create new separate line objects with the two new lines in the middle and removing the middle base line.
- When iteration is done, replace the main array with the temporary one and repeat for as many iterations you need.

For each iteration a single line is generating 3 additional lines but as you only deal with line objects it doesn't matter so much (in regards to complexity).

The center point will dictate the direction of the two new lines and you can use 1/3 as base for the length of the two new lines. All lines connect in the same end points.

Hope this helps.